# Functoriality of Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence - Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, cohomology, spectral-sequences

I'm interested in a text book reference on the functoriality of the [Atiyah–Hirzebruch spectral sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Hirzebruch_spectral_sequence). The only reference I found are these [lecture notes by Kupers](https://dongryul-kim.github.io/harvard_notes/Math231br2/Notes_Math231br2.pdf#page=52) (link should lead to the target page 52). Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A reference for the claim is Theorem 2.1 in the paper [A Generalization of the Atiyah–Hirzebruch
Spectral Sequence](https://access.portico.org/Portico/auView?auId=ark:%2F27927%2Fpgh2h1dbr60) by Mehdi Hakim-Hashemi and Donald W. Kahn.

Comment: I expect it is in Dyer's book "Cohomology Theories":

MR0268883  
Dyer, Eldon . 
Cohomology theories.
Mathematics Lecture Note Series 
W. A. Benjamin, Inc., New York-Amsterdam  1969

but my copy is in my office, and I don't get there very often right now.